# Converting a LINQ Inner join with Left Join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to implement a left join into my query, at the moment I'm getting a 'Object reference is not set to an instance of an object'.

The query is working perfectly as an inner join, but I want to include all rows from the left table despite if matches are found. I have tried to follow some of the previous posts on this, most refer to DefaultIfEmpty() but I'm failing to figure it out.

```
INNER JOIN - SQL
      SELECT TOP (1000) 
      FROM table1 as edc
      inner join table2 as c on edc.Id = c.Id
      inner join table3 as p on p.Id = c.Id
      group by p.Description
```

INNER JOIN - SQL

```
  SELECT TOP (1000) 
  FROM table1 as edc
  inner join table2 as c on edc.Id = c.Id
  left join table3 as p on p.Id = c.Id
  group by p.Description
```

INNER JOIN - LINQ

```
from edc in table1
   join q1 in table2 on __edc.Id equals q1__.Id
   join q2 in _table3 on q2.Id equals q1.Id 
   group q1 by q2.Description
   into grouped
   select new MyObj
   {
     Label = grouped.Key,
     Value = grouped.Count(),
    }
```

LEFT JOIN - LINQ

```
from edc in table1
       join q1 in table2 on __edc.Id equals q1__.Id
       join q2 in _table3 on q2.Id equals q1.Id  into leftJoin
       from p in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
       group q1 by p.Description
       into grouped
       select new MyObj
       {
         Label = grouped.Key,
         Value = grouped.Count(),
        }
```

Comment: Are you using LINQ to Objects? What is the type of `table1`? If so, your `p.Description` is the issue - there is no field `Description` when `p` is `null`. If it is LINQ to Objects, you can use `p?.Description`. It is traditional to re-use the range variable from the `join` in the left join `from`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.  We have three tables, with a left join between table1 and table2, and a second left join to table3.  You need to specify `DefaultIfEmpty()` on the two joins to include rows where there is no match in the right table.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var table1 = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, Description = "a"},
            new Item {Id = 2, Description = "b"},
            new Item {Id = 3, Description = "c"},
            new Item {Id = 4, Description = "d"}
        };

        var table2 = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, Description = "e"},
            new Item {Id = 2, Description = "f"},
            new Item {Id = 4, Description = "g"}
        };

        var table3 = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, Description = "h"},
            new Item {Id = 4, Description = "h"},
            new Item {Id = 5, Description = "i"},
            new Item {Id = 6, Description = "j"}
        };

        var leftJoin = from t1 in table1
            join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id into firstJoin
            from x in firstJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join t3 in table3 on x?.Id equals t3.Id into secondJoin
            from y in secondJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Table1Id = t1?.Id,
                Table1Description = t1?.Description,
                Table2Id = x?.Id,
                Table2Description = x?.Description,
                Table3Id =  y?.Id,
                Table3Description = y?.Description
            };

        Console.WriteLine("Left Join:");
        foreach (var i in leftJoin)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"T1Id: {i.Table1Id}, T1Desc: {i.Table1Description}, " +
                              $"T2Id: {i.Table2Id}, T2Desc: {i.Table2Description}, " +
                              $"T3Id: {i.Table3Id}, T3Desc: {i.Table3Description}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

        var grouped = from x in leftJoin
            group x by x.Table3Description
            into group1
            select new
            {
                Label = group1.Key,
                Count = group1.Count()
            };

        Console.WriteLine("Left Join Grouped:");
        foreach (var i in grouped)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Label: {i.Label}, Count: {i.Count}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Running the program yields the following output:

```
Left Join:
T1Id: 1, T1Desc: a, T2Id: 1, T2Desc: e, T3Id: 1, T3Desc: h
T1Id: 2, T1Desc: b, T2Id: 2, T2Desc: f, T3Id: , T3Desc:
T1Id: 3, T1Desc: c, T2Id: , T2Desc: , T3Id: , T3Desc:
T1Id: 4, T1Desc: d, T2Id: 4, T2Desc: g, T3Id: 4, T3Desc: h

Left Join Grouped:
Label: h, Count: 2
Label: , Count: 2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy, just change "from p" to "from q2":

```
   from edc in table1
   join q1 in table2 on __edc.Id equals q1__.Id
   join q2 in _table3 on q2.Id equals q1.Id  into leftJoin
   from q2 in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
   group q1 by p.Description
   into grouped
   select new MyObj
   {
     Label = grouped.Key,
     Value = grouped.Count(),
    }
```

Comment: You still reference `p` in the `group by`.